# The efficient way of comparing two paths in a network by using Java, when I have a large number of paths for comparision

Tags: java, compare

I have large number of generated paths, for each class. for example n1 is the number of paths for class 1. And in total the number of paths is M=sum(ni) i=1,2,..# classes, and I want to compare all the paths of different classes pair by pair to see if they have any node in common or not. Right now, I keep my paths for each class in a

```
ArrayList<List<Integer>>
```

and then for each path which is List I have a Boolean matrix by the size M*M ,  which has true value when a path has nothing in common with any other paths. And is false when it has something in common. But this is very time consuming. Do you have any data structure in mind, that may result in faster algorithm.
Thank you

Comment: It's still not clear what you are doing.  Post the part of your code that performs the comparison.

Answer (score 0):

If you can hash the nodes, create a HashMap> and put them into it, then scan through the values.

pseudo code:

```
    map: HashMap<Node, Set<Path>>
    paths: List<Path>

    foreach (path in paths)
      foreach (node in paths.Nodes)
        if (map.contains(node))
          set = map.get(node)
          set.add(path)
          map.put(node, set)
        else
          map.put(node, new Set(path))

   foreach (set in map.values)
     if (set.size > 1)
       // all paths in the set have a node in common
     else
       // there is only one path with this node
```